# A question about the dimension of topological products

Tags: general-topology

For each positive integer n, is the (small inductive) dimension of the topological product of n copies of the "long line", always equal to n? I ask because the "long line" is not a separable metric space. However, it is regular, and does therefore have a (small inductive) dimension.